# Python Regex (pattern + wildcard + pattern)[return](pattern)

Tags: python, regex

Scraping with `selenium` and parsing with `re` in python
from the string

```
<div type="copy3" class="sc-bxivhb dHqnfT">756 W Peachtree St NW Atlanta GA 30308</div>
```

I'm looking to return

```
756 W Peachtree St NW Atlanta GA 30308
```

This regex

```
("copy3").*?(?=</div>)
```

Gives me back

```
"copy3" class="sc-bxivhb dHqnfT">756 W Peachtree St NW Atlanta GA 30308
```

But I'd like to exclude everything up to the `>` before the  `756`

How do I include this?

Comment: Obligatory [don't parse HTML using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: What are you scraping and parsing with? there might be a better option than a complicated RegEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scraping with selenium, use selenium to get that...

```
my_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[type="copy3"]')
address = my_element.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Match a `>`, then capture non-`<`s that follow in a group, and extract that group:

```
type="copy3"[^>]+>([^<]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/BX2tVj/1

If you want to *match only* what comes after the first `<`, you'll either have to use lookbehind (which will only be reliable if you know exactly what the `class=""` attribute may contain):

```
(?<=type="copy3" class="sc-bxivhb dHqnfT">)[^<]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/BX2tVj/2

Or use the regex module instead, so you can use `\K`:

```
type="copy3"[^>]+>\K[^<]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/BX2tVj/3

```
import regex
str = '<div type="copy3" class="sc-bxivhb dHqnfT">756 W Peachtree St NW Atlanta GA 30308</div>'
match = regex.search(r'type="copy3"[^>]+>\K[^<]+', str)
```